# Changing Week feature value to DateTime format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset which includes a 'WEEK' feature.
This feature indicates the week number, which ranges from 1 to 400 as seen in the following dataframe excerpt:

```
data
Out[12]: 
         Store_id       SKU_id  WEEK  Units_Sold  QTY  PRICE Promotion  
0               2          294   298          11    1   2.62       NaN   
1               2          294   299           9    1   2.51       NaN   
2               2          294   300           6    1   2.49       NaN   
3               2          294   301           5    1   2.99       NaN
```

I now wish to add a new column to the dataframe which displays the date in  MM/DD/YY format.
All information I have is that WEEK 1 corresponds to the week date starting 09/14/89, whereas WEEK 400 corresponds to the week date starting 05/08/97.

the desired output would be something like this (referring to the previous dataframe):

```
data
Out[12]: 
         Store_id       SKU_id  WEEK  Units_Sold  QTY  PRICE Promotion      Date
0               2          294   298          11    1   2.62       NaN  05/25/95
1               2          294   299           9    1   2.51       NaN  06/01/95
2               2          294   300           6    1   2.49       NaN  06/08/95
3               2          294   301           5    1   2.99       NaN  06/15/95
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: There is an inconsistancy between your explanation and code in how you want the dates formatted. You say you want it formatted as `DD/MM/YY` but give them as `MM/DD/YY`.

Comment: Ah, i see i made an error there. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by creating a `datetime` to represent the zeroth week, then add each of the week offsets to it.

```py
start = pd.to_datetime( '09/14/89', format = '%m/%d/%y' )
df[ 'Date' ] = df[ 'WEEK' ].apply( lambda x: start + pd.DateOffset( weeks = x ) )
```

If you want to create a formatted string you can use the `strftime` function.

```py
df[ 'date' ] = df[ 'week' ].apply( lambda x: ( start + pd.DateOffset( weeks = x ) ).strftime( '%d/%m/%y' ) )
```

Comment: This seems to have solved my issue. Thank you very much!